# Time-changed squared Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

To build a deterministic time-changed Brownian motion, we have
$$\int_0^t \zeta_s dW_s \sim \int_0^t dW_{\xi_s} = \int_0^{\xi_t} dW_s = W_{\xi_t},$$
where
$${\xi_t}=\int_0^t \zeta_s^2 ds.$$
Is there a similar time change that can be built for $\int_0^t \zeta_s^2 dW_s^2=$$\int_0^t \zeta_s^2 (ds+2W_s dW_s)$ ?

---

Aside from the abusive notation, is it possible to reconcile the two following (it would work for $\zeta_t=$ constant)?

1. $\zeta_t^2 dW_t^2=\zeta_t^2 (dt+2W_t dW_t)=\zeta_t^2dt+2\zeta_t^2 W_t dW_t =d\xi_t+2\zeta_t W_t dW_{\xi_t}$
2. $dW_{\xi_t}^2=d\xi_t+2W_{\xi_t} dW_{\xi_t}$

Comment: What is this? In case you mean $\int_0^t \zeta_s^2\,dW_s^2=\int_0^t \zeta_s^2\,ds$ I would suggest $T_t:=t$ and $T_{\tau_t}$ with $\tau_t=\int_0^t \zeta_s^2\,ds\,.$

Comment: The answer is no. $\int_0^t \zeta_s^2 (ds+2W_s dW_s)$ is not a martingale and can therefore not be a time-changed BM. BTW in your first chain of equations the BM $W$ on the far left is different from the other three. Sloppy notation.

Comment: It is indeed an equality in distribution (I put a \sim sign). Having said that, it is not what I am asking. I am referring to the square of a BM which is obviously not a BM. How do you change time for a squared BM or a Bessel, if anything, or put another way, what relationship there is between a potential $W_{\xi_t}^2$ candidate and $\zeta_t^2dW^2_t$ ?

Comment: Correct. The square of a BM is obviously not a BM. You need to get rid of the drift $ds$  in $dW_s^2=ds+2W_s\,dW_s\,.$ You could do that by a Girsanov transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the abuse of notations... With $\xi_{t}=\int_{0}^t\zeta_{s}^2ds$,
$$W_{\xi_{t}}^{2}=\int_{0}^{\xi_{t}}dW_{s}^{2}
\\=\int_{0}^{\xi_{t}}(ds+2W_{s}dW_{s})
\\=\int_{0}^{t}(d\xi_{s}+2W_{\xi_{s}}dW_{\xi_{s}})
\\\overset{\mathrm{law}}{=}\int_{0}^{t}\left(\zeta_{s}^{2}ds+2\sqrt{\frac{\xi_{s}}{\zeta_{s}^{2}s}}\zeta_{s}W_{s}\zeta_{s}dW_{s}\right)
\\=\int_{0}^{t}\zeta_{s}^{2}\left(ds+2\sqrt{\frac{\xi_{s}}{\zeta_{s}^{2}s}}W_{s}dW_{s}\right)
\\=\int_{0}^{t}\zeta_{s}^{2}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{\xi_{s}}{\zeta_{s}^{2}s}}\right)ds+\sqrt{\frac{\xi_{s}}{\zeta_{s}^{2}s}}(ds+2W_{s}dW_{s})\right)
\\=\int_{0}^{t}\zeta_{s}\left((\zeta_{s}-\sqrt{\xi_{s}/s})ds+\sqrt{\xi_{s}/s}dW_{s}^{2}\right)$$

Comment: When you jump from $\int_{0}^{\xi_{t}}(ds+2W_{s}dW_{s})$ to $\int_{0}^{t}(d\xi_{s}+2W_{\xi_{s}}dW_{\xi_{s}})$ you do exactly what I said you cannot do, or at least, you should elaborate. Perhaps a Riemann-Stieltjes sum works.

Comment: Is it not a valid application of the Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz theorem for the $\int_{0}^{\xi_{t}}W_{s}dW_{s}$ part into $\int_{0}^{t}W_{\xi_s}dW_{\xi_s}$, considering a well-behaved and increasing $\xi_t$, $\xi_t<\infty$ and starting from 0?

Comment: The Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz theorem that I learned says that a martingale $M_t$ can be timechanged to become a Brownian motion. IMHO: To prove $\int_{0}^{\xi_{t}}W_{s}\,dW_{s}=\int_{0}^{t}W_{\xi_s}\,dW_{\xi_s}$ a look at Riemann-Stieltjes sums cannot be avoided and should be straightforward.

Comment: Yes. You are right. DDS is the next level that would show that $\int_{0}^{t}W_{s}dW_{s}=B_{\int_{0}^{t}W_{s}^{2}ds}$, for example, Revuz-Yor, chap. 5, sect. 1, prop. 1.6. I think the time change result should be alright, considering Revuz-Yor, chap. 5, sect. 1, prop. 1.5.

Comment: Yes. This is it. In the rest of your proof I don't see anything suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for your help (and for pushing...).

Comment: I thank you too. Learned something myself without doing too much work. :)

Answer (score 0):

We know
$$\tag{1}
W_t^2=t+2\int_0^tW_s\,dW_s\,.
$$
It is not an abuse of notation to write this as
$$\tag{2}
d(W_t^2)=dt+W_t\,dW_t\,.
$$
Further, it is not an abuse of notation to plug into (1) any $[0,\infty)$-valued stochastic process you like instead of $t\,:$
$$
W_{\xi t}^2=\xi_t+2\int_0^{\xi t}W_s\,dW_s\,.
$$
Since (2) is only a shorthand notation for (1) I think this is as good as it gets. I'd be careful messing around with expressions like
$$
dW_{\xi_t}^2=d\xi_t+2W_{\xi_t} dW_{\xi_t}\,.
$$
Formulas cannot take the burden away from us to know what we are doing.

If you analyse your attempt 1 in the same fashion (use always the integral form) you should quickly see where you run into problems.

Comment: I think I have the solution to my problem. $W_{\xi_{t}}^{2}=\int_{0}^{t}\zeta_{s}(\sqrt{\xi_{s}/s}dW_{s}^{2}+(\zeta_{s}-\sqrt{\xi_{s}/s})ds)$

Comment: At best this holds with $\sim\,.$ You have a proof?